# Why use Upper-Bounded Wildcards if it can't be used

Tags: java, generics

I don't understand why/when we should use Upper-Bounded Wildcards since you can not use it. Here is an example :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    static class Parent { }
    static class Child extends Parent { }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<? extends Parent> family = new ArrayList<>();
        family.add(new Child()); // 1. Doesn't compile
        family.add(new Parent()); // 2. Doesn't compile

        // List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<>();
        // List<Child> childs = new ArrayList<>();
        // parents.add(new Child()); // 3. Compile fine
        // childs.add(new Parent()); // 4. Doesn't compile
    }
}
```

The point 1 and 2 doesn't compile. From what I have understood this will not compile because `List<? extends Parent>` can be `List<Parent>` or `List<Child>`, and since you can not for instance add a Parent instance in a List, Java prevent us of doing this and gives a compilation error. So my question is what's the point in using Upper-Bounded Wildcards??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super

Comment: You know that List has methods other than `add`, right?